# How to grab twitter link from most websites - Python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am building a web crawler which scans websites for a twitter link. I am new to beautiful soup and I am having a very hard time. I have tried using regular expressions to parse the entire HTML of a page, but that worked less than beautiful soup. Currently my code grabs a website and attempts to parse it for a twitter URL.

Naturally i know this will not always work, but right now everything gets returned as None and never returns a twitter link, though I know the sites contain them. Further once ever 5 links i generally also received the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

which I have specifically tested against. I really don't think this should be this hard, but given it has been, I think I must be making a huge fundamental flaw with beautifulsoup which I am just not seeing. Any ideas?

```
def twitter_grab(url):
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11', 
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('a' or 'li')
    for tag in links:
        link = tag.get('href', None)
        if link is not None:
            text = re.search(r'http://www\.twitter\.com/(\w+)', link)
            if text is not None:
                handle = text.group(0)
                print handle
                return(handle)
```

Comment: can you provide a sample url so we can see what you are trying to parse, also you need to implement exceptions if you know that not every page will have twitter links.

Comment: You don't need all those headers, only `'User-Agent'`. You don't need 'li' tags. `get` returns `None` by default. Your regex grabs only  HTTP links. Other than that i dont see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Choose any random company website which has a twitter. The is None is being used instead of exceptions and should compensate. 

@t.m.adam, the 'a' does not return lines which are in lists, which tend to have links. An example I ran into would be Newyorklife.com

Comment: Is it okay for it to return only hyperlinks?  Or if they havn't created a hyperlink do you still want to find the twitter handle?

Comment: `find_all('a')` will find all 'a' tags in the document regardless of their parent tag. `tag.get('href')` returns `None` by default. Your regex won't match `http://twitter.com` or `https://www.twitter.com`. Also your function will return only the 1st `handle`.

Comment: What is the malfunction with Newyorklife.com then @t.m.adam. If you run just the 'a' command you will never get the twitter links on the page despite them being contained in the 'a'. If you run 'li' they will then appear. This has been a point of extreme confusion for me.

Comment: Still the expression `'a' or 'li'` shouldn't return more 'a' tags, but a list containing 'a' and 'li' tags. Let me take a look at the html, if i find soething useful i'll let you know.

Comment: I use a similar approach, but it goes super slow if the number of websites is a bit large, you had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically won't need regex in beautiful soup as each part is accessible, BS returns each tag as a dictionary so you can access the parameters as keys:

`handles = [ a["href"] for a in soup.find_all("a", href=True) if("twitter" in a["href"])]`

This will return all the parts that have been hyperlinked.  If a website, for some reason, hasn't wrote the `<a/>` tag this will miss it.